# Android app data recovery

Tags: android, backup, adb

Recently my Nexus 7 died somehow and had to reflash the factory android image. Luckily, my bootloader was already unlocked so I could save the important data using adb from recovery mode.

I also backuped the data of a game (at least I think so), simply saving

```
/data/data/com.my.game
```

I reflashed the factory image, the tablet runs well now. I also reinstalled the apps, including my game, then rooted the tablet so I could restore saved data to /data/data. Then I pushed the saves back to the folder (I had to be tricky because adb push did not work directly to /data, so I pushed it to /sdcard then copied it with adb shell as root).

Everything seems to be OK but unfortunately the game refuses to use the saved data, it simply crashes. When I restart my tablet, it runs again but without any saves, so I guess it deletes all saved data.

Could you give me any advice how to make my game work with the saved data?

Comment: it may be due to the permission of the files you pushed.Check and set them correctly then it might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the owner of all files under `/data/data/com.my.game`. It is possibly `root` and it should probably be `com.my.game` (or more precisely the userId of the app `com.my.game`, but most of the time they are the same).